# Tracing Win32 API calls in C++ program

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I know that there are some programs to trace Win32 calls in a live process. But I need some code to put into C++ code so that I can dump Win32 calls side by side with my current program trace. Has someone done this before?

Comment: All Win32 calls? Or only a few selected funcionts?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and study Microsoft Detours library to hook Windows API calls: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/.